# Laravel return array of custom DB::selects to view

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel, view

I'm creating a statistics function in my app but i seem to hit the wall.
 What i'm trying to do is to do few DB::select, put them into PHP array and return this array to view and then there do @FOREACH loop to display all values
Here's my question

***How can i return normal PHP array to view and use it in foreach loop ?***

**Here's the view that i'm using**

```
@extends('layouts.panel_main')

@section('content')
@foreach($stats as $key=>$value)
<p style="margin-left:200px;">Stats: {{ $value->from16_20 }} </p>
@endforeach

@endsection
```

This loop works great when I'm querying values from Model but for normal array it gives me this error
[image]

**Here's screenshot of dd of my array**
[image: screenshot of array]
**Here are controller functions **

```
//this function is for view
public function html_stats(Request $request)
    {
      //return flattened array of
     $stats =  self::stats_report("nazwa");

     return view('panel.html_stats')->with('stats',$stats);


    }

  public function stats_report($report_name)
    {

        $nazwa = $report_name; // the name of variable to be called
        DB::setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $oddane_glosy = DB::select('select count(created_at) as `Ilość głosów `from glosy;');
        $frekwencja_procentowa = DB::select('select count(glosy.id)/count(wyborca.pesel)*100 as `Frekwencja Procentowa` from glosy inner join wyborca on glosy.pesel=wyborca.pesel');
        //16_20
         $wiek1 =DB::select('select count(glosy.id) as `from16_20` from glosy inner join wyborca on glosy.pesel=wyborca.pesel where wiek>=16 and wiek<=20;');
    //20_40
    $wiek2 = DB::select('select count(glosy.id) as `from21_40` from glosy inner join wyborca on glosy.pesel=wyborca.pesel where wiek>=21 and wiek<=40');
    //40_60
    $wiek3 = DB::select('select count(glosy.id) as `from41_60` from glosy inner join wyborca on glosy.pesel=wyborca.pesel where wiek>=41 and wiek<=60');
    //wiecej niz 60
    $wiek4 = DB::select('select count(glosy.id) as `up60` from glosy inner join wyborca on glosy.pesel=wyborca.pesel where  wiek>60;');
        $data = array($wiek1,$wiek2,$wiek3,$wiek4);

        $merged = array_merge($wiek2,$wiek1,$wiek3,$wiek4); //array which consists of arrays: $wiek1 $wiek2 $wiek3 $wiek4
        return $merged;



              DB::setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS);
}
```

Comment: `$object->property` is for getting _object properties_. `$array['key']` is for getting _array values_. Change `$value->from16_20` to `$value['from16_20']` since `$value` is an array.

Comment: Why you used `setFetchMode` ?

Comment: I have an  excel statistics generator which is also using this function and it's easier for me to pass normal array instead of stdClass

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i get: Undefined index: from16_20

Comment: Ah, of course. You're array is a bit strange. Instead of doing `array_merge()`, create one array `$data = []` and add the results like: `$data['21_40'] = $wiek2;` and so on. Then you will have an array that can be fetch in the way of my first example.